# boolean expression in C

Tags: c, boolean, boolean-operations

I found this expression in a C program and I didn't get it :

```
 struct stack_rec *ss;                                          
 ss=(struct stack_rec *)EMalloc(sizeof(struct stack_rec));       
 if (ss) {                                                      
   int res;                                                     
   res = (ss->elem  = * i , 1); // what does this mean ????
   if (res <= 0)                                                
     return res;                                                
   if (*s == 0) {                                               
     ss->next = 0;                                              
   } else {                                                     
     ss->next = *s;                                             
   }                                                            
   *s = ss;                                                     
   return 2;                                                    
 }                                                              
 return 0;
```

What does `res = (ss->elem  = * i , 1);` mean? Is it a boolean expression? I've tried it with a 0 instead of 1 and it always returns the value of the second parameter! Can anyone explain this expression, please?

Comment: i think ss->elem  = * i is not a rvalue for res. Just computes and continues to 1(or 0) to get rvalue

Comment: it might have been `res = ss->elem  = * i;` originally. Then someone added `,1)` as a quick-and-dirty fix and it stuck. Does it make sense? We don't know what type `i` is.

Comment: some doc : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs06xbxh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/The-comma-operator.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks broken. It's a use of the comma operator, which simply evaluates to the value of the final expression, i.e. `1`.

Therefore, since that code is equivalent to:

```
ss->elem = *i;
res = 1;
```

The subsequent testing of `res` seem pointless, and thus broken.

Comment: It might be intended for ease of debugging. I.e. manually change the literal `1` in the source code to `0` to deactivate some features. That'd be the only reason I see to do this.

Comment: I guess this is not handwritten, it might be a hard-expanded macro or some other kind of generated code.

Answer (score 1):

The comma u see is a not very much used C operator.

Basically, what it does is execute the 2 statements (ss->elem = *i; and 1;). The statement 1; doesn't realy do much.

After that it returns the result from the last statement (in this case 1)